# Youtube API v3 without the need of End-User Authentication

Tags: php, upload, access-token, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

Im trying to create a Youtube upload script that does not require the end user to login in order to upload a video to my channel. The issue is I can gain the access token but it expires after an hour of being inactive. 
Also I am unsure where you can get the "refresh_token" from.

So essentially I wish to have this Google API v3 script not require any client side authentication in order to upload video's.

From what I gather from the API documentation at google if I had the "refresh_token" I could renew the token without the need of user interaction required.

Please see below my existing code on the matter.

```
<?php

$key = json_decode(file_get_contents('the_key.txt'));

require_once 'Client.php';
require_once 'Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();

$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY';
$REDIRECT = 'http://example.com/test.php';//Must be exact as setup on google API console
$APPNAME = "Test upload app";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$client->setRedirectUri($REDIRECT);
$client->setApplicationName($APPNAME);
$client->setAccessType('offline');

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
        die('The session state did not match.');
    }
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    //if session current save to file updates token key
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    echo '<code>' . $_SESSION['token'] . '</code><br>';
    file_put_contents('the_key.txt', $_SESSION['token']);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    echo "Token Expired<br>Attempt Refresh: ";
    $client->refreshToken($key->access_token);
    //refresh token, now need to update it in session
    $_SESSION['access_token']= $client->getAccessToken();
  }

    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Run Upload script here from google Youtube API v3
    //https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#resumable_uploads
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

} else {
    $state = mt_rand();
    $client->setState($state);
    $_SESSION['state'] = $state;
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    $htmlBody = '<h3>Authorization Required</h3><p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorise access</a> before proceeding.<p>';
}

?>



<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Uploads</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

If someone can look over this code and tell me what I'm missing would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out!!!

Thanks to [Burcu Dogan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92606/burcu-dogan) for the solution:

[Automatically refresh token using google drive api with php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905104/automatically-refresh-token-using-google-drive-api-with-php-script/#answer-15905618)

It turns out that the refresh_token will only be returned on the first $client->authenticate(), for that account you login with and you need to permanently store it remove the need for the user authentication.

As I had already authenticated desired user I was unable to regenerate the refresh_token with this project so I had to delete the project and recreate it.

Re-Authenticate the user and the refresh_token appeared! I then stored this token safe and have not had any issues since.

If you do not wish to delete your project and start again you can also go to [oAuth Playground](http://oAuth%20Playground) and aquire your refresh_token that way.

[YouTube run through](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfWe1gPCnzc)

Hope this help solve a lot of peoples problems online.