# Google Calendar API V3 Refresh Token Confusion

Tags: coldfusion, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am using the [CFC for the Google Calendar V3 API](https://github.com/billeatman/CF-GoogleCal-V3-Examples) by billeatman. I have integrated it successfully in my pages, where I go to login and authenticate and start working. My trouble starts when the authentication expires, even when the session is still active in my website.

I tried storing the structure returned by the Google API along with the Access_token and refresh_token in the database table. After storing, I am just confused. How do I call it? The above GIT Code just says like this:

```
<cfset application.oauth2.refreshToken() />
```

The function has the following code:

```
<cffunction name="RefreshToken" access="public" output="false" hint="I take the refresh_token from the authorization procedure and get you a new access token.">
    <cfset var strURL = base_auth_endpoint & "token">
    <cfhttp url="#strURL#" method="POST">
        <cfhttpparam name="client_id" type="formField" value="#variables.client_id#">
        <cfhttpparam name="client_secret" type="formField" value="#variables.client_secret#">
        <cfhttpparam name="refresh_token" type="formField" value="#getTokenStruct().refresh_token#">
        <cfhttpparam name="grant_type" type="formField" value="refresh_token">
    </cfhttp>
    <cfreturn manageResponse(cfhttp.FileContent)>
</cffunction>
```

But I am lost about how I pass the token I stored in my database to refreshToken. So what I tried is, calling the following two functions:

```
<cfset application.oauth2.SetRefresh_token('#getaccess.refreshtoken#')>
<cfset application.oauth2.SetAccess_token('#getaccess.accesstoken#')>
```

An error is thrown at this section:

```
<cfset application.oauth2.SetAccess_token('#getaccess.accesstoken#')>
```

It says "Method not found in the CFC". I am lost. **How do I keep the oauth2 alive for the google calendar, until I am logged out**.

```
<cffunction name="SetAccess_token" access="private" output="false" hint="setter for oauth access_token">
   <cfargument name="access_token" type="string" required="true">
   <cfset getTokenStruct()['access_token'] = arguments.access_token>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="SetRefresh_token" access="public" output="true" hint="setter for oauth refresh_token">
   <cfargument name="refresh_token" type="string" required="true">
   <cfset getTokenStruct()['refresh_token'] = arguments.refresh_token>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: any Update from any Experts, How can i proceed with this

Comment: Sorry, I couldnt find any examples in CFC. But you can check these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905104/automatically-refresh-token-using-google-drive-api-with-php-script and http://www.jensbits.com/2012/04/05/google-analytics-reporting-api-using-oauth-2-with-coldfusion/ which are in python. Also, you check oauth flow here https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: it seems this api is incomplete and left for the users to play with it, i had to switch back to @ray cfc, which seems a better option to me as of now

Answer (score 0):

The message, "Method not found in cfc" is because you are calling a private method, `SetAccess_token`, from outside of the cfc. `Access="private"` means it cannot be called from outside the cfc because its scope is private to the class. Change the function access to  `access="public"` and you can call it as you are, `classPath.publicFunction()`