# Google Drive API oauth2 hangs on live server and returns no error when authenticating with auth_code

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-php-sdk

I have a huge problem where absolutely no error is returned from google nor php.

I've written a google client oauth2 connect model, which is perfectly working when I'm running it on my dev environment on my mac (I'm not using a simple localhost, it's actually vagrant what I'm using to mirror the production server as much as possible) but it doesn't work when I push it to production.

It's just simply not returning any error. The code reaches the part where I have the auth code from Google and it hangs at the part where I'm trying to exchange it for a token ( $client->authenticate($auth_code) ).

I really don't know what am I doing wrong, since everything is working perfect without errors on dev site (which has a public link by the way, and I tried accessing it from different public IP addresses).

The moment I push the code to a live server, it just stops authenticating. I have the correct oauth credentials set up for every production server, redirect uri is correct. I simply don't know what am I doing wrong...

Here's a part of code (I repeat, it perfectly works on dev server with publicly accessible url):

```
$this->client = new Google_Client();
$this->credentials_path . '/client_secret.json'
$this->client->setAuthConfigFile($this->credentials_path . '/client_secret.json');
$this->client->setAccessType('offline');
$this->client->setRedirectUri($this->redirect_uri);
$this->client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY);
$this->client->authenticate($auth_code); //this is the part where the code hangs on a live server, but works perfectly on dev
$this->token = json_encode($this->client->getAccessToken());
$this->client->setAccessToken($this->token);
$this->writeTokenToFile($this->token);

if ($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $this->client->refreshToken($this->token);
}

$google_drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($this->client);
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you need to revoke the existing token before requesting another.

As mentioned in [Offline access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline), when you set the API client's access type to `offline`, the client object will refresh the access token as needed.

With that, you need to revoke access given to an application. As mentioned,

> part of the removal process can include an API request to ensure the permissions granted to the application are removed.

You may want to try [revoking a token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) by calling `revokeToken()`:

```
$client->revokeToken();
```

You may want to also check given solutions in the following SO posts:

- [Automatically refresh token using google drive api with php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905104/automatically-refresh-token-using-google-drive-api-with-php-script).
- [Not receiving Google OAuth refresh token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10857806)

Hope that helps!